# ContentDialog wasn't shown Over the Popup When Popup.ShouldConstrainToRootBounds=false in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have to open a Popup while clicking the button(Open Popup) and then from the popup while clicking the button(Open Content Dialog),I have to show a ContentDialog.

If I set Popup.ShouldConstrainToRootBounds=false ,the content dialog was shown below the popup. I didn't understand what's happening . I want to show ContentDialog over the Popup?

My complete Project link --> [Source Code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_Tz9oIuOkRfSsHpPzCoI7WRFK3RFaq5H?usp=sharing)

My Source Code :

Xaml :

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Open Popup</Button>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        popup = new Popup {  Margin = new Thickness(200, 300, 0, 0),ShouldConstrainToRootBounds=false };
        Border border = new Border { Width = 400, Height = 300, Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) };
        Button popupButton= new Button { Content = "Open Content Dialog", Width = 200, Height = 50 };
        border.Child = popupButton;
        popupButton.Click += PopupButton_Click;
        popup.Child = border;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
}

    private async void PopupButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentDialog contentDialog = new ContentDialog
        {
            Title = "ContentDialogOverPopup",
            Content = "Content Dialog",
            CloseButtonText = "Ok"
        };
        await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. When you set the `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` property to **false**, the popup is in its own top-level HWND. But the ContentDialog is still in the main XAML window handle (HWND).

When a popup with `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds = false` is first shown, it’s placed in its own window and shown in that context. That's why the PopUp is always on the top because it's in another layer. I'd suggest you not set this property to false if it is not necessary.

For more information, you could take a look at [Popup.ShouldConstrainToRootBounds Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.shouldconstraintorootbounds?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-xaml-controls-primitives-popup-shouldconstraintorootbounds).

Comment: then, how to achieve my case ? I want to drag popup outside,so i have to set ShouldConstrainToRootBounds to false. Is there any other way ?

Comment: @PremKumarShanmugam No. You can't set the `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` to false if you want to make the ContentDialog or another control on the top layer.